# Make part of $http.get URL dynamically generate

Tags: angularjs, api, http, dynamic, service

I'm pulling in an array from an API, like so:

```
  // in Service....

  return $http.get(
    'http://api.com/team/16110?Authorization=565eaa22251f932b9f000001d50aaf0b55c7477c5ffcdbaf113ebbda'
    ) 

        .success(function(data) { 
          return data; 
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
          return err; 
        });
```

This works fine, but only for the one array of data that the URL calls. I want to be able to call in other specific arrays by adapting one part of the URL - `16110`.

I want to be able to use a property from a separate property elsewhere within this $http call. I tried this:

```
'http://api.com/team/' + $scope.thisId +'?Authorization=565eaa22251f932b9f000001d50aaf0b55c7477c5ffcdbaf113ebbda'
```

But this just broke the Service.

Is there a relatively simple solution to this? I feel like I'm really close, but can't crack it.

---

### UPDATE - the following solution works...

---

### 1. SERVICE

```
    app.factory('DataService', ['$http', function($http) { 

    return {
        getTeamDetailsById: function(teamId) {
            return $http.get('http://api.com/team/' + teamId + '?Authorization=xxxxxx'
        )
    }


    }]);
```

### 2. CONTROLLER

```
app.controller('NationsController', [
    '$scope',
    'DataService',
    NationsController]);

function NationsController($scope, DataService) {

    self = this;

    DataService.getTeamDetailsById($scope.whichTeam).then(

    function(response) {
    //success callback
    $scope.teamDetails = response.data; 
    }, 

    function(response) {
    //an error has occurred
    });

}
```

### 3. response.data

I am expecting to get back an object from this. The API URL is fine, I've tried it directly and it returns the data ok.

Comment: Services don't have a $scope. Only controllers do. Note that success() and error() are deprecated, and that the whay you're using them, they're useless anyway.

Comment: Thanks - wasn't aware success() and error() are deprecated.

Comment: `$scope.teamDetails` has to be declared **outside** of your DataService call in order to use it.

Comment: I've been playing around with it, and whatever controller I call 'DataService' in, it crashes. If I do it in a single page controller, it will break all databinding for the page. If I call it in MainController, the whole site breaks. I've gone over and over it - it's injected in the controller, I've called it in a script on the index page. It seems there is something wrong with the syntax somewhere but I can't figure out where....

Comment: KKKKKKKK: My bad - it was a misplaced semicolon. It works now. Thank you so much! Been wrestling with this one for ages, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the `id` from the scope into the service:

```
app.factory("DataService", ["$http", function($http) {
    return {
        getTeamDetailsById: function(teamId) {
            return $http.get('path/to/api' + teamId + '?Auth=xxxx')
        }
    };
}]);
```

Call it from the controller:

```
DataService.getTeamDetailsById($scope.teamId).then(function(response) {
    //success callback
    $scope.teamDetails = response.data;
}, function(response) {
    //an error has occurred
});
```

Comment: That looks like the perfect solution... but it doesn't work! The $scope.teamDetails variable doesn't seem to hold any data. When I call it as an expression in the html it does nothing.

Comment: I can, but there's so many interdependent files - is there a way of dragging and dropping an entire file structure into plunker, or do you have to copy and paste every individual file?

Comment: Only the relevant code.  (1)  What does your service look like?  (2)  What does your main controller look like?  (3)  What are you expecting to come back from `response.data`?

Comment: Please see update, all relevant code added and questions responded to.

Answer (score 0):

This:

`'http://api.com/team/' + '$scope.thisId' +'?Authorization=565eaa22251f932b9f000001d50aaf0b55c7477c5ffcdbaf113ebbda'`

is equal to `http://api.com/team/$scope.thisId?Authorization=[...]`, which is not what you want. Remove the quotes around `$scope.thisID`, like this:

`'http://api.com/team/' + $scope.thisId +'?Authorization=565eaa22251f932b9f000001d50aaf0b55c7477c5ffcdbaf113ebbda'`

This will work assuming you've set `$scope.thisId` to whatever resource's ID you want to fetch.

Comment: Sorry - that was a typo. It wasn't in quotes on the original, still doesn't work...